# С помощью какого запроса можно преобразовать данную таблицу (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо после каждого клиента добавить строку с номером клиента и значением NULL.

Результат выглядит так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «После» учитывая какую сортировку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что пришло в голову, это `UNION ALL`
и сортировка:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
    FROM t_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT client, CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS date
    FROM t_1
) AS t_2
ORDER BY client ASC
       , date   ASC NULLS LAST
;
```

Результат:

```
 client |    date    
--------+------------
      1 | 2020-09-12
      1 | 2020-09-17
      1 | NULL
      2 | 2020-10-02
      2 | NULL
(5 rows)
```